# How to restart windows service through Python script?

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, restart

I am creating a script to restart windows service through Python script but getting the below error:
[Script error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A9Bq.jpg)

**Code:**

```
import win32serviceutil

class serviceRestart:

     serviceName = "MySQL57"

     win32serviceutil.RestartService(serviceName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     lm = serviceRestart()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message pretty much says it all. You **need** to install the module.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

If you have pip installed then you can use "pip install pypiwin32"